# Why does System.Buffer.BlockCopy take int instead of long?

Tags: c#-4.0, stream

Is there a reason `System.Buffer.BlockCopy` takes `int` parameters instead of `long` for the offset/length of the copy? Streams generally work with `long`, why would `BlockCopy` not have an overload that takes `long`, too?

Comment: For convenience, you can use Array.Copy with a int64 index. But it won't be as efficient as BlockCopy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because prior to .NET 4.5, no object could exceed 2 gigabytes. So there was no reason to have more than an int to represent the length.

Even in .NET 4.5, although an array can be more than 2 gigabytes in length, it can't have more than 2^31 items. So the maximum size of a `byte[]` is still 2 gigabytes (minus a little overhead). The maximum size of an `int[]` is 2^31 items or about 8 gigabytes, etc. See [gcAllowVeryLargObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).