# How to copy byte[] data into a very large float[]?

Tags: c#, copy

I am trying to copy byte[] data into a float[] like this:

```
float[] floatArr = new float[int32.MaxValue];
byte[] byteArr = new byte[bufferSize];
// fill buffer
Buffer.BlockCopy(byteArr, 0, floatArr, 0, bufferSize);
```

This works fine, because I am copying it to the start of the destination array.
But how can I copy the data to an index greater than int32.MaxValue?

```
long pos = (int32.MaxValue * sizeof(float) - 1) - bufferSize; // copy to the end of the array
Buffer.BlockCopy(byteArr, 0, floatArr, pos, bufferSize); // Buffer.BlockCopy() does not accept long as destination index
```

Comment: How much memory do you have on your machine?

Comment: Mmmh... there is the `Buffer.MemoryCopy`... But it requires `void*`, so unsafe code... Sadly you discovered a missing API... You can have arrays of up to `uint.MaxValue` elements, but there are many API that don't support them

Comment: Non-response about this argument: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15487546/613130

Comment: If you really need, you can always copy the data manually... `BitConverter.ToSingle()`, one float at a time.

Comment: @xanatos I saw the Buffer.MemoryCopy option, but I don't know how to turn a float[] into a void*. (void*)byteArr doesn't work

Comment: Have you got gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `Buffer.MemoryCopy` you can do something like:

```
int bufferSize = 4096;
// The maximum size is 2146435071
// see https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element
// And the page is even wrong. If maximum index is 2146435071,
// then maximum size should be 2146435071 + 1
float[] floatArr = new float[2146435071];
byte[] byteArr = new byte[bufferSize];

int ix = 0;

fixed (float* fl = floatArr)
fixed (byte* b = byteArr)
{
    while (ix < floatArr.Length)
    {
        // Read data to byteArr;
        int bytesRead = ReadToBuffer(byteArr);

        //bytesRead must be divisible by sizeof(float), so divisible by 4

        float* fl2 = fl + ix;
        Buffer.MemoryCopy(b, fl2, bytesRead, bytesRead);
        ix += bytesRead / 4;
    }
}
```

Note that the method must be marked as `unsafe`, and you must permit unsafe code inside your program (it is an option in the Project)